# Django Rest Framework: Including multiple choice fields in Serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django Rest Framework to create a custom API for my `Movies` model which is defined as follows:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Movies(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    GENRE_CHOICES = (('Adventure', 'Adventure'), ('Family', 'Family'), ('Fantasy', 'Fantasy'),
                        ('Musical', 'Musical'), ('Sci-Fi', 'Sci-Fi'), ('Drama', 'Drama'), ('War', 'War'),
                            ('Romance', 'Romance'), ('Comedy', 'Comedy'), ('Thriller', 'Thriller'),
                                ('Crime', 'Crime'), ('Horror', 'Horror'), ('History', 'History'), ('Family', 'Family'),
                                    ('Animation', 'Animation'), ('Short', 'Short'), ('Western', 'Western'),
                                        ('Action', 'Action'), ('Biography', 'Biography'))
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 128, choices = GENRE_CHOICES)
    imdb_score = models.FloatField()
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

Now, I want to allow the admin of the application to enter new instances of the `Movies` model into the API. I want the `genre` field to be a multiple choice field, i.e. the admin should be able to select more than one genres for a particular movie.

serializers.py

```
from shoppy.models import Movies
from rest_framework import serializers


class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #genre = serializers.CharField(max_length = 128, choices = Movies.GENRE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = ('popularity', 'director', 'genre', 'imdb_score',
                        'movie_name')
```

However, at the API endpoint, the admin is only able to select one `genre` from the given list of choices. I do know that if I was working with forms, this is how I would have implemented a multiple choices checkbox:

```
genre = forms.CharField(max_length = 1230, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
                                                    choices=Movies.GENRE_CHOICES))
```

How do I implement multiple choice fields in Serializers, so that the admin could chose more than one genre in the API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The root issue is with your model:

```
genre = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
```

Your model only allows to store a single value in that column hence DRF (Django Rest Framework) enforces same restrictions in the API. If you want users to be able to select multiple genres, the easiest solution is to introduce a `Genres` model with which `Movies` will have m2m relationship:

```
class Genres(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Movies(models.Model):
    genres = ManyToManyField(Genres, related_name='movies')
```

Comment: What changes should I make in my `serializers.py` corresponding to the above changes you mentioned in my `models.py` ?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ has some examples. I dont remember necessary changes off hand.

Comment: I made the required changes. However, I'm still encountering some bugs which I have mentioned in detail in a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409484/django-rest-framework-implementing-many-to-many-relationship-in-serializer