# Django Rest Framework: Implementing Many-to-Many relationship in Serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django Rest Framework to create a custom API for my Movies model which is defined as follows:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Genres(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)

class Movies(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genres, related_name = 'movies')
    imdb_score = models.FloatField()
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

Now, in my application, each `genre` can have multiple `movie` instances and vice versa. As a result, there is a Many-to-Many relationship between the `Genres` model and the `Movies` model. I want to allow the admin to chose multiple genres for a particular movie while posting new `Movies` instances at the API endpoint.

serializers.py

```
from shoppy.models import Movies, Genres
from rest_framework import serializers


class GenresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Genres

class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = ('popularity', 'director', 'imdb_score', 'genres',
                        'movie_name')
```

views.py

```
from shoppy.models import Movies
from rest_framework import viewsets
from shoppy.serializers import MoviesSerializer


class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Movies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoviesSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from shoppy import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movies', views.MovieViewSet)
# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /movies/
Exception Value: no such table: shoppy_genres
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you done `$./manage.py makemigrations` and `$./manage.py migrate` since creating the `Genre` model?

Comment: Yes I have. Still encountering the same error.

Comment: Look at the generated migration files. Do you see the tables you would expect? (most likely `shoppy_movies`, `shoppy_genres`, and `shoppy_movies_genres`)